# jQuery - change from live() to on()

Tags: jquery, methods, live

I have the following code and would like to change from using the live() method to using the on() method:

```
$('.commenttext').live('keydown', function(e) {
    if ((e.which == 13) && !e.shiftKey) {
        comment($(this));
        return false;
    }
});
```

It is about commenting on a post - also one that was created created on the fly using the on() method. If I simply change only the word "live" to "on" like this

```
$('.commenttext').on('keydown', function(e) {
    if ((e.which == 13) && !e.shiftKey) {
        comment($(this));
        return false;
    }
});
```

then it only works with items that weren't created on the fly.

UPDATE 1

I changed the code to the following:

```
$('.commentsDiv').on('keydown', '.commenttext', function(e) {
    if ((e.which == 13) && !e.shiftKey) {
        comment($(this));
        return false;
    }
});
```

with commentsDiv being the parent element of commenttext, but still it doesn't work with elements that were created on the fly. For example, the following function creates the commentsDiv on the fly:

```
$('#postDiv').on('keydown', '#posttext', function(e) {
    if (e.which==13 && !e.shiftKey) {
        post($(this));
        return false;
    }
});
```

Does anyone know how to adjust properly?

Thanks :)

Comment: You need to attach the callback to a **static** parent of `.commenttext` *static* means exist on page load.

Comment: @gdoron, the only thing i would change about that sentence is to say that the parent exists at the time of event binding. The advantage of `live` (document delegate) binding is that it can be done *before* the page is finished loading, and even before document.ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to attach the callback to a static parent of .commenttext static means exist on page load.

Example:

```
$('body').on('keydown', '.commenttext', function(e) {
    if ((e.which == 13) && !e.shiftKey) {
        comment($(this));
        return false;
    }
});
```

Or:

```
$('{staticParentElement}').on('keydown', '.commenttext', function(e) {
    if ((e.which == 13) && !e.shiftKey) {
        comment($(this));
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The `live` form is actually a delegate using `document`, so the new format would be:

```
$(document).on('keydown', '.commenttext', function...);
```

Typically it's better to use a nearer consistent parent of the selector (in this case `.commenttext`) that isn't changing with the contents, but `document` should work for most cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can use nearest *static* parent element as event holder. However, you can also use `body`:

```
$('body').on('keydown', '.commenttext', function(e) {
    if ((e.which == 13) && !e.shiftKey) {
        comment($(this));
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: @Dennis have you tried with the static parent element? Check if it works with `body` then it should anyway work.

Comment: We all are glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('parentElement').on('keydown', '.commenttext', function(e) {
    if ((e.which == 13) && !e.shiftKey) {
        comment($(this));
        return false;
    }
});
```

Substitute "parentElement" for the parent element of .commenttext.