# Fixing broken plugin to use jQuery .on() instead of .live()

Tags: jquery, plugins

Updated site to latest WordPress version (5.5.1) and unfortunately a plugin broke.

I found the SO ([jQuery - change from live() to on()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466465/jquery-change-from-live-to-on)) helpful and I know *what* needs to be done but I don't know how to apply it to the existing syntax. This is a WordPress plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/netgo-expandablecollapsible-menu/#description) that isn't being supported by the developer any more (couple of years now). I'd like to try and update the plugin to work with WordPress 5.5.1 instead of having to find a new plugin and update every page that used the old plugin.

The existing code is

```
$netgo_navigations.find("ul li").live("click", function(e) {
```

and I believe I need to provide a static parent (which I have) but I don't know how to apply it to the current syntax as shown above. My assumption was I could simply change `.live` to `.on` and it would be fixed since I thought the `.find()` would provide the 'static' parent but that doesn't seem to be the case.

```
$netgo_navigations.find("ul li").on("click", function(e) {
```

What else do I need to do?

NOTE: I originally asked my question on the wordpress.stackexchange.com site and they said it was off topic because it was more JavaScript-centric than it was WordPress so I'm asking my question here.

Comment: Maybe you're after `$netgo_navigations.find("ul").on("click", "li", function(e) {` - https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: That did not work. :(

Comment: What about `$netgo_navigations.on("click", "ul li", function(e) {`?

Comment: I need to go back to your first comment. There was a second line that I missed. When I updated both references, the issue was fixed. Thanks User!